# Using ReplaceAll on SparseArray

Tags: replacement, sparse-arrays

I'm using `SparseArray` in a notebook in which I am doing complex conjugation manually, i.e. writing $\sqrt{-1}$ as `i` and applying `/.{i->-i}` to perform complex conjugation.

I noticed that `ReplaceAll` or `/.` doesn't seem to work on `SparseArrays`, e.g.

```
m = SparseArray[{2, 2} -> i];
m /. {i -> -i}
```

just returns `m`. Any clues on how to get around this quickly?

Comment: is it necessary to do this without converting to a normal array?

Comment: Hm yes I could convert it to normal, perform conjugation, and convert back to sparse. Would be nice if this can be done on the sparse array though.

Comment: You can't use `I` (and then `Conjugate[]`)?

Comment: If You are working with own "i" why don't You write own `conjugate[]` function? You can pack there sparse array conversion and use Your transformation rule.

Comment: @mmal yes that's what I've been doing. I just thought this adds computational steps that might be avoided if /. can be used in a straight-forward manner on sparse arrays.

Comment: @J.M. I've always had trouble with complex conjugation in mathematica, e.g. Conjugate[a] not being simplified even when I declare a to be real etc. But the conjugation was just meant as an example for the general issue of /. in sparse arrays.

Comment: popffabrik I see that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  Are you dissatisfied with the ones you have received?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

J. M. has shown you a workaround using `ArrayRules` and as others mentioned, using `Conjugate` is more prudent. However, to answer your primary question — *"Why doesn't `ReplaceAll` work on `SparseArray`?"*, it is because `SparseArray` is **atomic**.

In other words, `SparseArray` objects are "indivisible" and the data contained in them can only be accessed in specific ways (e.g., using undocumented arguments to `SparseArray`) and not by manipulating its `FullForm`. You can verify that it is indeed atomic, whereas a regular matrix is not:

```
AtomQ@m
(* True *)

AtomQ@Normal@m
(* False *)
```

A similar situation arises with `Graph` objects, which are also atomic. For instance, the following will not work:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 4}] /. DirectedEdge -> UndirectedEdge
```

even though `// FullForm` will show the presence of `DirectedEdge` in the structure. Hence it is important for you to know which objects are atomic before you try (unsuccessfully) to use replacement rules on them.

To the best of my knowledge, the [list of atomic objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46850) (not including undocumented ones) include those with the following heads:

```
{Symbol, String, Integer, Real, Rational, Complex, SparseArray,
 BooleanFunction, Graph}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful to know.

Answer (score 31):

Use [`ArrayRules[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayRules.html):

```
m = SparseArray[{2, 2} -> i];
mc = SparseArray[ArrayRules[m] /. i -> -i, Dimensions[m]];
MatrixForm[mc]
```

$\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-\mathtt{i}\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 8):

**Updated to work in M13**

**Issue**

Consider the internal structure of a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object. For example:

```
s = SparseArray[{1, 0, 1, 0}];
s //InputForm
```

> SparseArray[Automatic, {4}, 0, {1, {{0, 2}, {{1}, {3}}}, {1, 1}}]

Clearly doing something like:

```
s /. 1 -> 3
```

should not convert the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object into:

```
SparseArray[Automatic, {4}, 0, {3, {{0, 2}, {{3}, {3}}}, {3, 3}}]
```

which is not even a valid [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object *(the above replacement is prevented because [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects are atomic)*.  Instead, to work properly, [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) needs to do a replacement on the equivalent [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) version. Getting this to work right is not easy, which is most likely why it doesn't work. There is too much variety in the patterns and levels that can be used in a replacement.

*By the way, it is possible to do replacements of entire [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects, which is very convenient, as will be seen below*

That doesn't mean that the only way to do a replacement on a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) is to use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) or [`ArrayRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules) and then convert back, though. Assuming you just want to apply a replacement rule on the elements of a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) object, here are two possibilities.

**SparseArray iterator**

If you have a 1-D vector sparse array, you could use a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) iterator. For example, here is a function that uses a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) iterator to do replacements of a vector [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray):

```
VectorReplaceElement[s_SparseArray, rule_] := Table[Replace[i, rule], {i, s}]
```

The key here is that `rule` is applied to each element of the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray), that is, the level of the replacement is constrained. Applying this function to my initial example:

```
r = VectorReplaceElement[s, 1 -> 3];
r //OutputForm
% //Normal
```

> SparseArray[<2>, {4}]

> {3, 0, 3, 0}

We see that the replacement has happened as desired. Note that the speed depends on the number of nonzero elements in the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray). For example:

```
s = SparseArray[Thread[2^Range[40]->1]];
s //OutputForm
```

> SparseArray[<40>, {1099511627776}]

It would require a computer with many TB of memory to be able to convert this [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) to a normal matrix.

```
new = VectorReplaceElement[s, 1->3]; //MaxMemoryUsed //AbsoluteTiming
new["NonzeroValues"]
```

> {0.000049, 2360}

> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}

Clearly the replacement worked, and the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) was not converted to a normal matrix in order to do the replacement. This method doesn't work as well for higher rank [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects.

**Structural replacement**

The other possibility is to extract the nonzero elements, and the default element, apply the replacement rule, and then reconstruct the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray). Here is a function to do this (updated to work with M13):

```
ReplaceElement[s_SparseArray, rule_] := With[
    {
    elem = Replace[s["NonzeroValues"], rule, {1}],
    def = Replace[s["Background"], rule]
    },
    
    SparseArray[
        Automatic, 
        s["Dimensions"], 
        def, 
        {1, {s["RowPointers"], s["ColumnIndices"]}, elem}
    ]
]
```

Again, this approach does not convert the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) to a normal matrix:

```
new = ReplaceElement[s, 1->3]; //MaxMemoryUsed //AbsoluteTiming
new //OutputForm
new["NonzeroValues"]
```

> {0.000073, 4016}

> SparseArray[<40>, {1099511627776}]

> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}

And it works fine with higher rank [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) objects:

```
s = RandomInteger[1, {10, 10}] //SparseArray;
new = ReplaceElement[s, 1->10];
new //OutputForm
new["NonzeroValues"]
```

> SparseArray[<54>, {10, 10}]

> {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}

Comment: The structural replacement no longer works  in Mma 13. The best I could do is `SparseReplaceAll[s_SparseArray, rule_] := SparseArray[s["ExplicitPositions"] -> Replace[s["ExplicitValues"], rule, Infinity], Dimensions@s, s["ImplicitValue"] /. rule]`. I don't know if that's optimized, though.

Comment: @SimonRochester Thanks for letting me know. I updated to work in M13.