# List of atomic expressions

Tags: expression-manipulation, built-in-symbols

I was surprised to see `Graph` objects are atomic. Is there a way (through documentation or programmatically) to find all atomic heads?

The ones I know of are:

```
Integer
Rational
Real
Complex
Symbol
String
SparseArray
StructuredArray
Image (* since v9 *)
Image3D
Graph
ColorProfileData
Association
MeshRegion
BoundaryMeshRegion
Language`ArrayObject
ByteArray
QuantityArray
RawArray
RawData
Audio
```

Are there any others?

### Others mentioned in the comments

```
Internal`Bag
System`Utilities`HashTable
System`RawArray
BooleanFunction
Dispatch (* since v10 *)
Dataset
```

### Neural net functionality

```
AggregationLayer
BasicRecurrentLayer
BatchNormalizationLayer
CatenateLayer
ConstantArrayLayer
ConstantPlusLayer
ConstantTimesLayer
ContrastiveLossLayer
ConvolutionLayer
CrossEntropyLossLayer
DeconvolutionLayer
DotLayer
DropoutLayer
ElementwiseLayer
EmbeddingLayer
FlattenLayer
GatedRecurrentLayer
ImageAugmentationLayer
InstanceNormalizationLayer
LinearLayer
LocalResponseNormalizationLayer
LongShortTermMemoryLayer
MeanAbsoluteLossLayer
MeanSquaredLossLayer
NetChain
NetDecoder
NetEncoder
NetEvaluationMode
NetExtract
NetFoldOperator
NetGraph
NetInitialize
NetMapOperator
NetModel
NetNestOperator
NetPairEmbeddingOperator
NetPort
NetPortGradient
NetReplacePart
PaddingLayer
PartLayer
PoolingLayer
ReplicateLayer
ReshapeLayer
ResizeLayer
SequenceAttentionLayer
SequenceLastLayer
SequenceMostLayer
SequenceRestLayer
SequenceReverseLayer
SoftmaxLayer
SpatialTransformationLayer
SummationLayer
ThreadingLayer
TotalLayer
TransposeLayer
UnitVectorLayer
```

Comment: Strangely, `SparseArray`s are actually not atomic, but just treated for most purposes as if they were. They are the only non-atomic atoms, though, as far as I know. And in addition to your list, there are several other undocumented atomic objects as well, such as the `Internal\`Bag`, the `System\`Utilities\`HashTable`, the `System\`RawArray`, and probably others besides. Several objects that should be atomic (by the standards of the `SparseArray`) aren't, such as `CompiledFunction` and `LibraryFunction`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. :  see help file on `AtomQ` : like `Complex`and `Rational` numbers, `SparseArray` is atomic. List 'm using `Cases[ Names["System`*"], _?AtomQ]`

Comment: @Wouter the definition of an atomic object is one that "cannot be divided into subexpressions" (although I would argue that a better definition is that its structure does not correspond to its `FullForm`). `SparseArray` clearly can be, regardless of whether `AtomQ` is true or false. Further down the documentation page for `AtomQ` we see some discussion about this, which shows the contradiction inherent in considering `SparseArray`s as atomic. Now, it may be that `SparseArray` truly is atomic in terms of its underlying implementation, but unlike other atoms it has a meaningful `FullForm`.

Comment: The same question on Stack Overflow: [(5964469)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5964469)

Comment: What is atomic and what isn't changes with versions.  `Image` isn't atomic in v7 and v8.

Comment: Associations should *not* be Atomic, based on the documented definition we currently use for what atomic means (doesn't have arbitrary subparts, can't be Mapped, etc). I hope we'll be taking that flag off in the next few point releases.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon but on the other hand since `<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>[[1]]` does not equal `a -> 1` as seen in `FullForm[<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>]`, shouldn't it be considered atomic?

Comment: @ChipHurst AtomQ is defined as "an expression which cannot be divided into subexpressions", and has notes such as "You can use AtomQ in a recursive procedure to tell when you have reached the bottom of the tree corresponding to an expression." and "AtomQ gives True for any object whose subparts cannot be accessed using functions like Map". Clearly Association should not be AtomQ by these measures. But as you point out, it is also not NormalQ (which would mean that it behaves like its FullForm), if we had such a thing. AtomQ and NormalQ are currently "mixed together", we should separate them.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon I would find it confusing if Associations were not `AtomQ`.  If an expression is compound (not atomic) that usually implies that it always behaves as one would expect based on its full form, including for the purposes of pattern matching, part extraction, etc.  This is a simple and predictable model, so I think that there's value in preserving it.  Also consider that `Hold[Association[1->2]]` is a true compound expression.  If `Association` is not considered atomic any more, then `Hold[Association[1->2]]` should behave precisely the same way as ...

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon ... `With[{a = Association[1 -> 2]}, Hold[a]]`.  But it doesn't, there are differences (again, part extraction, pattern matching).  Also consider `SparseArray`, which also has parts, but again doesn't behave identically to its FullForm.  `SparseArray` is also marked as `AtomQ` for this reason.  Perhaps you could consider changing the description of `AtomQ` in the documentation instead of letting `AtomQ` return `False` for associations.  What `AtomQ` *really* means is a bit complicated, but it's valuable to have it, and changing it would break either consistency ...

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon ... or backwards compatibility, and has the potential to cause a lot of confusion.  Of course the decision is up to you, I'm just trying to explain why Association is indeed AtomQ according to my mental model of what is atomic.  It is definitely true that it is not as simple as "an expression which cannot be divided into subexpressions", but the real question is not whether AtomQ follows this definition.  It is: which kind of AtomQ is a practically useful function?  The actual one or the one that would be based on this simple definition?

Comment: Dataset is atomic

Comment: @Rojo Thank you!

Comment: `Raw` is outdated, but it is still atomic.

Comment: @Xavier `Graphics` objects are not atomic. Try running `AtomQ[Graphics[{Circle[]}]]` or `First[Graphics[{Circle[]}]]`.

Comment: Let me also note, that `AtomQ[Underflow[]]` is `True`. `Underflow[][[0]]` is `Real`, but `Hold[Underflow[]][[1,0]]` is `Underflow`. But `Hold[Evaluate[Underflow[]]][[1, 0]]` is `Real` again, despite that `Hold[Underflow[]]` and `Hold[Evaluate[Underflow[]]]` look identical in `FullForm`. The same note applies to `Overflow[]`.

Comment: Another word of caution: `Hold[1/2]`, `Hold[2^-1]`, `Hold[Evaluate[1/2]]` and `Hold[Rational[1,2]]` are all different expressions despite that some of them have the same `FullForm` and reported as identical by `SameQ`. Among them, `Rational` is atomic only in `Hold[Evaluate[1/2]]`. Also, it is not atomic in `Rational[1, 2] &`. So, `Rational` is not _necessarily_ atomic, but only after it has had an opportunity to be evaluated. The same applies to other heads. The exact structure and atomicity of expressions may be not always preserved by `Uncompress[Compress[…]]]`.

Comment: Also, it may seem surprising that both `AtomQ[Infinity]` and `AtomQ[ComplexInfinity]` are `False`. Both symbols are converted to expessions with `DirectedInfinity` head when evaluated, but it remains hidden both in `StandardForm` and `InputForm`.

Comment: You also can create an atomic list if you want: `{AtomQ[Raw[List, ""]], Head[Raw[List, ""]]}`. But I suppose it counts as cheating.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can executive the code in mma 10 or above version

```
EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"]//EntityList
```

But is not all atomic function,as I know.

Comment: Wow, very nice!

Comment: I'm accepting this because only a few (documented System heads) are missing: `Integer`, `String`, `Symbol`, `QuantityArray`. The first three make sense I think. For example you can't create an integer using the head `Integer`.

Comment: [Tell me how to. :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xufcf.png)

Comment: @yode You can create a true symbol still:   a = Symbol["s"];s === a

Comment: @user18792 Ah, right. I guess `Integer` and `String` are the only 2 then.

Comment: I just stumbled across this and in V12.3.1 the expression in the answer returns a list which includes `Integer`, `String`, `Symbol` and `QuantityArray`.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's the only "answer" I can see to post (as CW) there is also [`BooleanFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanFunction.html) as [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5964469) pointed out by [Sasha](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38/sasha).

---

In version 10 `Dispatch` tables are atomic.<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54691/121)</sup>

```
Array[# -> 2 # &, 5] // Dispatch // AtomQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: The same as association. `<|a -> 1|> // AtomQ` gives `True`.

Comment: @YiWang `Association` is already mentioned in the Question body above, but yes.