# Make symbols atomic, without losing their type

Tags: symbolic, tensors, symbols, data-types

So, I'd like to define a matrix M, that does not decompose into it's constituents when I do things like `Tr[M]`, but I also want it's type to be retained.

(By type, I mean, what sort of a data structure it is, integer, or matrix, or vector, not literally the data-types available.)

For example:

In: `Tr[a*M]`

Out: `a*Tr[M]`

The solution from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61625/66144) answer doesn't seem to retain the type.

Is there any way to do this?

Edit:
Basically, have an atomic symbol whose type is say a 2*3 matrix (or whatever is the equivalent of that in Mathematica), but whose individual elements don't matter for computation.

If I define a matrix as follows:

`M = {{a,b},{c,d}}`

Then, `Tr[M]` gives `a+d`. But I don't want the symbol to expand that way.

I'd like `Tr[M]` to give `Tr[M]` but `Tr[a*M]` to give `a*Tr[M]` and have other linear functions expand similarly.

Comment: I do not understand the question (not even what you mean by "type") ...  a lot more explanation is needed, with concrete examples and a clear explanation of the motivation. Please edit and update the question.

Comment: "have an atomic symbol" makes no sense because all symbols are atomic. `{{a,b},{c,d}}` is not atomic, and is not a symbol. Thus, do not give a value to `M`, keep it as a symbol, and look up symbolic tensor manipulations in the docs. Perhaps this is what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use my `TensorSimplify` package help with this. Install the paclet with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Once installed, you can load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

This package defines the helper functions `ToTensor` and `FromTensor`. `ToTensor` converts expressions containing [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) and [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) into the equivalent version using [`TensorContract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorContract), and `FromTensor` does the opposite. So, your [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) expression can be simplified with:

```
$Assumptions = M \[Element] Matrices[{3, 3}] && a \[Element] Complexes;

FromTensor @ ToTensor @ Tr[a M]
```

> a Tr[M]

An alternative is to just use the package's `TensorSimplify` function:

```
TensorSimplify @ Tr[a M]
```

> a Tr[M]

`TensorSimplify` will work for more complicated arguments to [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr):

```
TensorSimplify @ Tr[a M + a^2 M.M]
```

> a Tr[M] + a^2 Tr[M.M]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and for writing this useful package!

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps what you want is symbolic tensors: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html

```
$Assumptions = M ∈ Arrays[{3, 3}] && a ∈ Complexes;

TensorContract[a*M, {{1, 2}}]
(* a TensorContract[M, {{1, 2}}] *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How come this doesn't work with the function Tr, since it's just a specific case of TensorContract?

Comment: @MahathiVempati I don't know, I'm not experienced in this area. But TensorContract was introduced specifically for _symbolic_ tensor manipulations. Not every function supports this functionality.