# Get List of All Atomic Expressions

Tags: core-language

```
Cases[Names["System`*"],x_:> If[StringTake[x, 1] == "$", Nothing, If[AtomQ@ToExpression[x], ToExpression[x], Nothing]]]
```

This still gives me a list of atoms which are actually Built-in Function heads. How do it find and remove them to get a list of all available true atoms.

Comment: Have you seen `WolframLanguageData[EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", "Atomic"]]`? (It's not complete; `Integer` and `Real` are not there, for example.) [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46850) is a previous thread.

Comment: Yes, but how do i get the complete list, from the list which i have after the evaluation of the code.