# ReplaceAll does nothing with the rgb values of a picture

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, image

In the book "Programming with Mathematica: An Introduction" at the beginning of the chapter on Patterns and rules an example is given where the colors of an image are transformed according to

```
image=Import[...];
image./{r_,g_,b_} :> 1-{r,g,b}
```

and the negative of the image is returned.

When I tried to apply this to an image nothing happened though. I checked the `FullForm` which returned

```
Image[RawArray["UnsignedInteger8",List[
    List[List[111,117,129,255],List[136,139,162,255],List[124,126,149,255],List[62,42,49,255]],
    List[List[85,92,97,255],List[144,149,171,255],List[99,98,107,255],List[91,15,7,255]],
    List[List[50,60,53,255],List[87,105,92,255],List[150,143,89,255],List[141,120,57,255]],
    List[List[82,98,86,255],List[67,81,71,255],List[149,146,97,255],List[106,95,51,255]]]],
"Byte",Rule[ColorSpace,"RGB"],Rule[Interleaving,True]]
```

So it turns out that 4 numbers ranging from 0 to 255 are used to determine the colors of the pixels but even when I execute `image./{r_,g_,b_,x_}:>{255-r,255-g,255-b,x}`
nothing happens.

I also tried `Replace[image,{r_,g_,b_,x_}:>{255-r,255-g,255-b,x},Infinity]` but to no avail.

Does anybody know why nothing happens?

Comment: In a nutshell: `Image[]` was not [atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46850) when that book was written, but now it is. Look up `ReplacePixelValue[]` and use that instead, or work with the result of `ImageData[]` first before converting back to an image.

Comment: @ J.M is computer-less: Thanks a lot! Do you by any chance have a reference to a list of all atoms in the latest version of mathematica?

Comment: Click on the link in my last comment.