# Why variable in SparseArray can't be replaced?

Tags: replacement, sparse-arrays

```
SparseArray[{1, 1} -> t] /. t -> 1
```

Still contains t. Why t is not replaced by 1?

Comment: Atomic objects don't really work like that. Anyway: use `ArrayRules[]` to convert to a list of nonzero entries and their corresponding positions, make your replacements, and then convert back to `SparseArray[]`.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/using-replaceall-on-sparsearray